# Custom labels in Symfony Translation bundle

Tags: symfony

I use in my Symfony project the "a2lix/TranslationFormBundle" and i have a issue with custom labels for translation fields.

If i set a custom label (hintText, see below) the form in frontend show label "Text".

**My twig output**

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

**My Form fields**

```
$builder->add('variable', 'text', array('label' => 'variable', 'translation_domain' => 'messages', 'attr' => array('maxlength' => 255)))
                ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
                            'fields' => array(
                                'text' => array(
                                    'field_type' => 'textarea',
                                    'label' => 'hintText',
                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'rte')
                                ),
                                'explanation' => array(
                                    'field_type' => 'textarea',
                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'rte')
                                )
                            )
                ));
```

I check this documentation for custom labels

https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle/blob/0.x/README.md

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has nothing to do with the a2lix bundle, the labels must be translated on your form_theme or directly in your twig file like:

```
{{form_label(form.entity.text, form.entity.text.vars.id)}}
```

and then in your translation file:

```
my_form_type_pet_name: "This is an hint"
```

You can find more information [here](http://sf.khepin.com/2012/01/form-label-translation-in-symfony-2/).

Comment: I'm not sure how must look my twig template? In my example i have subfields for field "translations"